# How to draw android UI components from XML on my website?

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I want to render XML files and provide a layout preview at my website. The same functionality that android studio performs when we write a XML and studio preview tool draws the design along side. I am not sure how to do it at my server side which is running on `react.js`.

I want to store all my XML files at server side and then draw view from those XML files. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: well, you can use same way as Android studio does - use same jar on your server. But you will be required to have Java there. Then after renderring, you can just return an image to the web page.

Comment: Dear  Vladyslav Matviienko , thank you for the comment. Do you have any resources where i can find how Android studio works for the same. As I was trying to find but unable to get needful. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used this search query: `java render android layout xml` and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932236/rendering-an-android-xml-layout-in-java You will be able to find much more